# Javafx character encoding mismatch

Tags: character-encoding, javafx

I am using netbeans 7.3.1 on mac osx 10.6.8

PROBLEM: 
when I drop the following files:

```
照片.jpg
picture.jpg
blank space.txt
```

I get

```
not found %E7%85%A7%89%87.jpg
dropped picture.jpg
not found blank%20space.txt
```

while I expected

```
dropped 照片.jpg
dropped picture.jpg
dropped blank space.txt
```

QUESTION: how do I ask JavaFX to use the same character encoding as my OS?

ALTERNATIVE QUESTION: how do I ask JavaFX and Mac OS X to use UTF-8 as default character encoding?

ANSWER: see answer given by Petr, it doesn't answer the question but it points to the real problem.

CODE:

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SimpleDropFile extends Application {
    private VBox root = new VBox(10);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.setOnDragOver(onDragOver);
        scene.setOnDragDropped(onDragDropped);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    EventHandler onDragOver = new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            if (db.hasFiles()) {
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
            } else {
                event.consume();
            }
        }
    };

    EventHandler onDragDropped = new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;
            if (db.hasFiles()) {
                success = true;
                for (File file:db.getFiles()) {
                    if(file.exists()){
                        root.getChildren().add(new Label("dropped " + file.getName()));
                    } else {
                        root.getChildren().add(new Label("not found " + file.getName()));                        
                    }
                }
            }
            event.setDropCompleted(success);
            event.consume();
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I updated my question to include:

1. a proper question
2. minimum sample code. now you can copy, paste, compile and test. maybe it works properly on windows
3. the answer

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "doing wrong"? Please explain what does not work.

Comment: JavaFX 2.x on OS X 10.6 is not a supported configuration (only OS X 10.7.3+ is supported).  I wonder how you even got JavaFX installed and running on your machine.

Comment: @jewelsea: I just "lied" to Netbeans installer when it asked me what version of OS X its running. (i.e. I modified the file /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist)

Comment: @Uooo: I updated my question, now it has a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about this bug in JavaFX: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23541

It was fixed in JavaFX 8. You could test it on the Early Access release from here: http://jdk8.java.net

Comment: it would be nice if JavaFX 8 fixed it, but what does https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23541 say? I don't want to sign up

Comment: It's a link to the JavaFX bug tracker and this particular bug says: The Dragboard (DragEvent.getDragboard()) contains invalid files when the dragged file path contains spaces or special characters. It could be useful to have an account there if you are interested in JavaFX.

Comment: that's exactly the problem I am getting. is there a workaround for jdk7? or do I have to wait jdk8?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to wait for jdk8. I don't think there's a workaround